# Dir gets me a filepath, but then I can't open it or read a timestamp

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

So I have a bit of a strange one, I suspect it's related to some sharepoint setting somewhere.

I have a little VBA function to loop through all files in a folder, and pick out the most recent one. It's something like:

```
Function LoopThroughFiles(FolderToScan, FileCriteria)
Dim LatestDate as Date
Dim LatestFile as File
Dim StrFile as String

StrFile = Dir(FolderToScan & "\*" & FileCriteria) 'I have no idea why I need the extra \*, it works though

Do While Len(StrFile)>0
    Debug.print StrFile
    If FileDateTime(FolderToScan & StrFile) > LatestDate then
        LatestFile = StrFile
        LatestDate = FileDateTime(FolderToScan & StrFile)
    Else
        'Do nothing
    End if

StrFile = Dir

Loop

LoopThroughFiles = LatestFile
End Function
```

Now, this is running through 20 different folders. For the first 19, it works perfectly. On the last one, it's failing. Dir pulls in the filepath, but then FileDateTime fails, and when I pass through the correct result to the function, the code's unable to open the file. I've manually checked that the resulting filestring is correct (using both eyes and code). This was working last week, and now it's failing, even on folders it scanned properly last week.

Anyone have any ideas?

(PS: I know the extra "\*" is probably wrong but for some reason it seems to be right and working... I dunno... The given foldertoscan has a "\" at the end already)

Edit: I've checked with the sharepoint admins, the folder I'm grabbing out of has no other different settings than anyone else

Comment: Really dumb question - the files/folders on the last loop is there, right?

Comment: Yeah, I can see them, I can open the files, DIR gets me filenames - it's just once it has all that, it can't open/timestamp them

Comment: Are you trying to get the newest file out of all of the folders? or just of each?

Comment: alos what doe sthis do? FileDateTime

Comment: It tells me when a file was last modified/uploaded

Comment: you should post that code too since its related.

Comment: I mean, sure... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filedatetime-function

Comment: If you add another directory, will it still fail on the last one - in other words, is the current "dirX" the problem, or is it always "dirLast"?

Comment: Always dirX - reshuffling the order that they're scanned in results in dirX being the problem